# Angular $resource, save and re-render

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-resource

I'm using `$resource` to interact with my backend.
I've a page that shows the list of items coming from `$resouce.query()` .

```
gcResourceClubs.query({
            page:(($scope.currentPage - 1) * $scope.itemsPerPage),
            size:$scope.itemsPerPage})
        .$promise.then(function(res){
                $scope.clubs = res
            });
```

(I use a promise because the values are used to set the pagination in the html)

Now, in another directive (the one of the form) I perform this operation.
`gcResourceClubs.save(club);` which saves the club to the server. 
(*I tried with `scope.clubs.$save(club)` but it `POST` data as url encoded rather than a json object, so it does not work with my backend*. I thought that in this way the list of object would be automatically updated, is it true?)

Now, when the resource is created, how can I *easily* re-render the list?
I thought of making a promise over the `save` and do the same logic as of the `promise` of the query. Or to redirect the app to the page that display the list.

What is the "correct" way to do this? Isn't there anything automated for this? (I used for a while backbone, and there I had events, but in angular with directives and controllers I'm not sure that's the correct way of doing it)

Comment: you schould call query again in order to resfresh your grid...

Comment: So on your save the backend makes some changes to the club and returns them from the POST? Then you want those displayed in the list without requerying the whole page?

Comment: ideally yes. but i can't just append the object to the current `$scope.club` list since it's bounded to the pagination (it will result in showing 11 elements instead of 10)

Comment: inside the directive i can't assign the result of the query to `$scope.clubs` (it misses the provider) i can only assign it to `scope.clubs` inside the `link` function, but this does not work.